# Compiling Squirrel Code

Tags: squirrel

I am new to Squirrel based scripting. Whenever I am trying to compile the program using the GCC compiler. I am getting the following error:

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I am trying to compile the code on a 64bit mac.

I am new so please excuse me if this is a really dumb question.

Comment: For a start, you should tell, where did you download sources.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the compilation you have to modify the `Makefile` under `SQUIRREL3/sq/` by removing the `-s` flag from the `g++` command.

Example:

```
sq64:
    g++ -O2 -s -m64 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_SQ64 -o $(OUT) $(SRCS) $(INCZ) $(LIBZ) $(LIB)
```

becomes:

```
sq64:
    g++ -O2 -m64 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_SQ64 -o $(OUT) $(SRCS) $(INCZ) $(LIBZ) $(LIB)
```

Hope it helps.